# Cannot simplify `if` statement condition

Tags: ruby

Here is a function to count in an `if` statement the vowels contained in a string:

```
 def count_vowels(string)
 sum = 0
  n = 0
  while n < string.length
    if string[n] == "a"||string[n]=="i"||string[n]=="u"||string[n]=="e"||string[n]=="o"
      sum += 1
    end
    n+=1
  end
  return sum
end
```

I found the repetitive `string[n] ==` being redundant and replaced it with:

```
if string[n] == ("a"||"i"||"u"||"e"||"o")
```

However, in this code, the function does not return the correct counts. Why does the simplified `if` statement not work here?

Comment: search within the literal `"aeiou"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test whether a variable equals either one of two values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196414/test-whether-a-variable-equals-either-one-of-two-values)

Comment: @Stefan shows you how to replace all the code in your method with one 21-character line. Isn't Ruby wonderful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `a == (x || y)` is *not* expanded to `a == x || a == y`.

Instead, `a` is compared against the result of `(x || y)`.

```
if string[n] == ("a"||"i"||"u"||"e"||"o")
```

is equivalent to:

```
if string[n] == "a"
```

because:

```
("a"||"i"||"u"||"e"||"o") #=> "a"
```

If you want to simplify your code, use [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-count):

```
def count_vowels(string)
  string.count('aeiou')
end
```

Comment: You should probably mention in the answer that it won't cater for capital letters. This might answer the question, but the OP probably wants to `count_vowels` which should probably be lower and upper case vowels.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question

```
string[n] == ("a"||"i"||"u"||"e"||"o")
```

This part `("a"||"i"||"u"||"e"||"o")` would always evaluate to `"a"`

so you are essentially writing

```
string[n] == "a"
```

A better way to do this might be

```
def count_vowels(my_string)
  mystring.chars.count{ |c| c  =~ /[aeiou]+/i }
end
```

You could also extend the string class for fun

```
class String
  def vowels_count
    chars.count{ |c| c  =~ /[aeiou]+/i }
  end
end
```

Comment: Or even better: `'foobar'.count('aeiou') #=> 3`.

Comment: OP = Original Poster, the person who wrote the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can do what you want but the reason it doesn't work is because `("a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u")` is evaluated by ruby to return the first of those characters that isn't `false` or `nil`. Essentially that clause *always* returns `"a"`:

```
2.2.1 :001 > ("a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u")
=> "a"
```

This means that you are always testing if `string[n] == "a"` which is clearly not what you are aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return correct count because `||` in `if string[n] == ("a"||"i"||"u"||"e"||"o")` evaluates to the first non-false condition, in this case, `"a"` (it is not `nil` or `false`), so basically it is the same as `if string[n] == "a"`.You can try with `include?` :

```
%w( a i u e o).include? string[n]
```

or `in?`:

```
string[n].in? %w( a i u e o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add regular expersion

```
 def count_vowels(string)
 sum = 0
  n = 0
  while n < string.length
    if string[n] =~ /[aiueo]/ # will match a, i, u, e or o
      sum += 1
    end
    n+=1
  end
  return sum
end
```

You can even more simplify your code

```
def count_vowels(string)
  string.split('').select{|char| char =~ /[aeiou]/}.length
end
```

will do the same functionality

```
  string.split('')
```

will give you array of characters

```
.select{|char| char =~ /[aeiou]/}
```

will select only 'a' 'e' 'i' 'o' 'u' characters

```
.length
```

will count number of those characters

Comment: This is not answering the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement doesn't work because `== ("a" || ...)` doesn't tell Ruby to check if it's equal to any of these. Instead, it evaluates `("a" || ...)` and checks if `string[n]` is equal to that.

The "proper" simplified expression would be this:

```
string[n] =~ /aeiou/i
```

Assuming you want case-insensitivity, that is. If not, use this:

```
string[n] =~ /aeiou/
```

Note that with this solution you'll have to escape any regex metacharacters (`.`, `[]`, `()`, etc.)

If you don't want to do that, use something like this instead:

```
['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].include? string[n]
```